# executing xquery and getting string as result using saxon

Tags: java, string, expression, xquery

hi i am using saxon to run a xquery in java.
i want to get the result in a strig as xml formatted to pass this result to a string variable and convert it to Json format. The issue is that i can´t get the result as string.
any idea thanks.

```
 StaticQueryContext sqc= c.newStaticQueryContext();
       DynamicQueryContext dqc =new DynamicQueryContext(c); 
//     Processor processor = new Processor(sqc);
       final XQueryExpression exp = sqc.compileQuery( queryFinal  ) ;

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( xmlText.getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) );
        InputSource XMLSource=new InputSource(is);
        SAXSource SAXs=new SAXSource(XMLSource); 
        DocumentInfo DI=sqc.buildDocument(SAXs);
        dqc.setContextNode(DI);

         Properties props=new Properties();
           props.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml");
           props.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");

       exp.run(dqc,new StreamResult (destStream),props);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/// Everything as above, just change the last line to....

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

exp.run(dqc,new StreamResult (stringWriter),props);

String result = stringWriter.toString();

System.out.println("Result: " + result);